# unzip command ends successfully without unzipping file

Tags: unix, encryption, compression, zip, gunzip

There are double compressed files with extension xxx.zip.gz

On gunzip - xxx.zip file is created of size 0.25 GB
On unzip after gunzip - xxx.zip file extension does not change

Output of unzip :

```
Archive:  xxx.zip
  inflating: xxx.txt
```

also

```
echo $? shows 0
```

so, even though zip command completed successfully and still the file remains with zip extension , any help ?

OS - SunOS 5.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're finding the xxx.txt is being created, right?

`unzip` and `gunzip` have different "philosophies" about dealing with their archive. `gunzip` gets rid of the `.gz` file, while `unzip` leaves its `zip` file in place. So in your case, zip is working as designed.

I think the best you can do is

```
 unzip -q xxx.zip && /bin/rm xxx.zip
```

This will only delete the zip file if `unzip` exits without error. The `-q` option makes `unzip` quiet, so you won't get the status messages you included above.

**edit**

as you asked `when zip file itself is +10 GB in size, then unzip does not succeed`

Assuming that you are certain there is enough diskspace to save the expanded orig file, then it's hard to say. How big is the expanded file? Over 2GB? SunOS5 I believe, used to have file-size limitation at 2GB, requiring a 'large-file' support to be added into kernel and utilities. I don't have access to Sun anymore so can't confirm. I think you'll find places to look with `apropos largefile` (assuming your `$MANPATH` is setup correctly).

But the basic test for did the `unzip` work correctly would be something like

```
  if unzip "${file}" ; then
     echo "clean unzip for ${file}, deleting the archive file" >&2
     /bin/rm "${file}"
  else
     echo "error running unzip for ${file}, archive file remains in place" >&2
  fi
```

(Or I don't understand your use case). Feel free to post another question showing `ls -l xxx.zip.gz xxx.zip` and other details to help reconstruct your expected workflow.

IHTH.

Comment: yeah I find that unzipped file really got created without .zip extension separately which I was overlooking. It however seems that sometimes when zip file itself is +10 GB in size , then unzip does not succeed. Can we do something for this case ?

Comment: first off, I noticed that you show OS=Sun5.1. Stuff is very different on vendor OS's. Did you comb thru the `man zip`? Maybe there is an option that will auto-delete a clean upzip. (I looked on my Linux before writing this answer, and I couldn't find an auto-delete, maybe it is there, but I don't think so). 2. did experimentation show you that a .zip.gz file is small er than a `gzip -9 file` (maximum compression). Put another way, not clear why you're using 2 forms of compression. Is it that you receive it from a 3rd party?

Comment: I think Sun5 has `b(un)zip2` which, while slower, when using it's max compression mode with `-9` will generally make file 1/2 size of a `gzip -9` file. Could that help?

Comment: .zip and .zip.gz are same in size 0.25 GB, the uncompressed file itself is 0.47 GB in size. gzip -9 is 0.24 GB itself -  Its from 3rd party and I can't do much here.. I however found bunzip2 but don't see auto delete option

Comment: I think `bunzip2` will autodelete, after a clean expansion of archive. Good luck.